# Face Recognition and Comparison using opencv4.8.0 in scala

Tags: scala, opencv, intellij-idea, face-recognition

I'm working on **OpenCv4.8.0 library** to **compare two faces** (in Images) whether they belong to same person or not.

I'm using **scala** (version **2.13.4**), **sbt** (version **1.9.6**) and **Intellij** idea as IDE.

Here is my code

```
import org.opencv.core.{MatOfDMatch, MatOfKeyPoint, _}
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs
import org.opencv.features2d.{DescriptorMatcher, SIFT}
import scala.collection.convert.ImplicitConversions.`list asScalaBuffer`
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._ 

object FaceRecognition extends App {

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

  val selfieImage = Imgcodecs.imread("/home/image1.jpg")
  val driverLicenseImage = Imgcodecs.imread("/home/image2.jpg")

  val sift = SIFT.create()
  val keyPoints1 = new MatOfKeyPoint()
  val descriptors1 = new Mat()
  val keyPoints2 = new MatOfKeyPoint()
  val descriptors2 = new Mat()

  sift.detectAndCompute(selfieImage, new Mat(), keyPoints1, descriptors1)
  sift.detectAndCompute(driverLicenseImage, new Mat(), keyPoints2, descriptors2)

  val matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE)
  val matches = new java.util.LinkedList[MatOfDMatch]
  matcher.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches, 2)


  val goodMatchesList = matches.toList
    .filter { m =>
      m.toArray()(0).distance < 0.75 * m.toArray()(1).distance
    }
    .map { m =>
      m.toArray()(0)
    }

  val javaGoodMatchesList = goodMatchesList.asJava
  val filteredMatches = new MatOfDMatch()
  filteredMatches.fromList(javaGoodMatchesList)
  val similarityScore = filteredMatches.size().height / keyPoints1.size().height

  println(s"Similarity Score: $similarityScore")

  val similarityThreshold = 0.7
  if (similarityScore > similarityThreshold) {
    println("The images are likely of the same person.")
  } else {
    println("The images are likely of different persons.")
  }
}
```

Above code is working fine if the faces in images are exactly same, but when I test it with my current image and my 2,3 years old picture it detects them as different images although they are quite same.

I have change value of **similarityThreshold**

```
val goodMatchesList = matches.toList
        .filter { m =>
          m.toArray()(0).distance < 0.75 * m.toArray()(1).distance
        }
        .map { m =>
          m.toArray()(0)
        }
```

also I have changed the comparison value (**0.75**) but still it is behaving same.

Guide me how can I achieve above functionality? Do I need to train some model (If yes then how can I do this)?